# when retrieving an array element, how can I use a variable as the element number

Tags: c

I am working on some code to parse log data, this part in particular is used to translate the decimal form of a month to a human form ( so 1 would be jan ), and to accomplish this I am trying to use a combination of a for loop and an if statement, and had thought that I could simply use a variable as the number for the statement to retrieve the array cell, but it did not work out as expected, so if someone could offer advice as to how I can do this I would really appreciate it, thanks!
(here is the main chunk of the code)

```
for ( x = 0; x < 11; x++ ) {
    int altint = 1 + x;
    if ( dmon == altint ) {
            printf( "%s\n", field_month[x] );
            {break;}
    }
}
```

Comment: what is in `field_month`, and `dmon`?

Comment: field month is an array with the human names of the months, so { jan, feb, march, etc } and then dmon is the decimal version of the month

Comment: oh shit actually had made a dumb mistake, had mixed up the name of the array itself and the numerical reference to the month, works perfectly now though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you *not* use a `for` loop and instead look up the element that you want directly:

```
printf("%s\n", field_month[dmon]);
```

If your `dmon` is 1-indexed (`1` for *January*, .., `12` for *December*), then a slight change:

```
printf("%s\n", field_month[dmon-1]);
```

Comment: @Evan, note that tpaksu updated his answer to include `dmon-1`.

Comment: True, but your explanation is clear and concise. I updated my comment.

Comment: thanks! and if I wanted to save the output would I just save the output of printf to a variable?

Comment: @lacrosse1991: You'd have trouble saving the _output_ of `printf(3)` to a variable -- it, after all, prints to a standard IO stream. Probably better would be something like `char *month = field_month[dmon];`. (That gives you a _pointer_ to the data -- it doesn't make a copy of it. That will be important later. :)

Comment: thanks! worked perfectly as well, sorry if those were dumb questions, still getting the hang of things, the speed at which C operates at though is well worth it :)

Comment: C only runs as quickly as you can program it to run. It's remarkably easy to write bad programs in any language. :D

Comment: Indeed lol, although even at this point in time, the full program executes in .001 seconds compared to the bash alternative which takes around .1 seconds, not a noticeable difference to the end user but nice to have the peace of mind :) plus once I get going on C, will have a good basis to use if/when I give c++ a try, etc in the future if desired

Answer (score 2):

just `printf("%s",field_month[dmon])` or `field_month[dmon-1]` as it depends on your month names array?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop can be optmized to:

```
if (dmon >= 1 && dmon <= 12)
{
    printf("%s\n", field_month[dmon]);
}
```

Because the only thing it's really doing is preventing an invalid index of being used to access your array...

Comment: Good point about avoiding bad array accesses -- but arrays are zero-based and thus indexed from `0` to `11` -- unless a bogus element is stored in the first array position.